# Programmatically hiding an SPField

Tags: sharepoint

I'm having trouble hiding a SPField from the user view programmatically.

I tried the obvious way of:

```
SPField newField = web.Site.RotWeb.Fields.GetField("order");
string newField = list.Fields.Add(newField);
list.Fields["order"].Hidden = true; // <--- exception: read-only field
list.Update();
```

The exception says the field is read only so I can't modify it.

This field is added in the code and hence it'll be unghosted from the field collection.  Besides from the UI, how can I make the field hidden?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try setting [ReadOnlyField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.readonlyfield.aspx) to false (then back to true after setting Hidden).

If that does not work, check the value of [CanToggleHidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.cantogglehidden.aspx). If CanToggleHidden is false, you can either:

- Override it with reflection as in [this example](http://sanjayapdl.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/hide-and-unhide-sharepoint-fields-through-reflection/).
- Add the field using XML as in [this example](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/08/how-to-add-hidden-field.html). Note: if you need to use an existing site column, you can try adding ID attribute with the column's Guid to the XML string.
- Skip Hidden and use [ShowInDisplayForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showindisplayform.aspx), [ShowInEditForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showineditform.aspx), and [ShowInNewForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showinnewform.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I saw that you are adding the field. try getting a new instance of the field after it is created and then applying the hidden atttribute before updating the list.